# How do I enable snap window to corner in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: window, window-manager, gnome-shell, mutter, snap-windows

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 where Unity Tweaks had this dialog:

[image]

(I would normally have the top and bottom "do nothing"'s set to "top" and "bottom" as well)

Working with both large monitors and portrait monitors this functionality is invaluable. It's also the default on Windows 10 which is the other operating system I get to deal with.

I can't seem to find a place to configure this (or appropriate GNOME extension) on Ubuntu 18.04, where is it?

P.S. I did find equivalent settings is CCSM but GNOME seems to be ignoring them.